# List to Label, Crashes on Bad User Input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a novice. I'm an artist learning Python for an installation I'm making. I apologize if I say or do dumb things.

-

I've created a piece of software that will take user input, output a synonym, and ask the user if the synonym is correct. It crashes when the user inputs a word incorrectly, or a word that isn't in the APIs dictionary (I use that word in the non-pythonic sense, not `dict`). with a `strvalue = " ".join(json_obj["synonyms"])KeyError: 'synonyms'`  I want to fix this, and have the software display something like "please try again" on bad input. Because crashes are lame. Here's what I *think* is a minimal reproducible example. You can't actually run it from this (can't do that without pasting my whole damn script), but maybe you can tell me what's wrong.

````
``` # this is the API that gets the synonyms - the url must be www.URLURLURL.URL.com/words/ENTRY HERE!!/typeof

    url = "https://wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com/words/"+Entry_1.get()+"/synonyms"

    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-host': "wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com",
        'x-rapidapi-key': "TheAPIkey"
    }



    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers,)




    response = response.text
    json_obj = json.loads(response)
    strvalue = " ".join(json_obj["synonyms"])

    stringtolist = strvalue.split()

    print(stringtolist)

    listA = stringtolist

    finaloutput = (random.choice(listA))
    print(finaloutput)




    label = Label(root, text= finaloutput, font="helv 48", bg="black", fg="white", )
    label.pack(expand=1,) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you know an error might occur, you can use what's called a `try/except` block. What's happening is in the name: you basically tell your program to `try` something, `except` a specific error occurs, in which case you'd like to do something else. Since you know when your error occurs, you can handle it accordingly:

```py
word = Entry_1.get()  # I guessed this is the user input, it makes sense to keep a reference in a variable

try:
    strvalue = " ".join(json_obj["synonyms"])  # This is the error-prone line.
except KeyError:  # You know which error to expect
    # Do whatever you want in case the error occurred. It would make sense to 
    # somehow let the user know they made an error.
    # Also, look up f-strings if you haven't come across them, they're great.
    print(f"The word '{word}' is not in the dictionary. Please choose another")
```